# Side effects of smoking cessation

Tags: mental-health, smoking, depression

It's been a year since I quit smoking, but this year has been one of depression and counter-productivity at work. Is it common to experience things like this? If so, how long should it last?

Comment: Physiologic nicotine withdrawal only lasts a few weeks.  The behavioral and psychological addiction lasts much longer.  Even so, it is much more likely that you had depression while you were smoking (and were self-treating with nicotine).  Smoking cessation is a very poor explanation for depression.  You should consider speaking to a health professional about your symptoms.

Comment: Maybe i should add that i actually did smoked one or two roll-your-owns every month.

Comment: Yes please. Are those one or two cigarettes per month the total amount you smoked? Also, how long did you smoke before you quit?  Length and intensity of withdrawal symptoms can be partially dependent on how much and how often you smoked, so that information would be helpful. I'll wait to hear from you. Congrats on your first anniversary! You're strong and brave, and a great example for others! Give yourself a big reward :)

Comment: @Sue nope, i smoked 1-1.5 packs a day five years since i was seventeen  years old! I'm even thinking that maybe i should start smoking again!

Comment: Thanks for the information. It will help me, or anyone else, give you a better answer. I've been counseling people in your position for many years, so believe me when I tell you that what you're feeling is normal. Starting again is tempting, but it won't help. You can make it through this :) –  Sue 52 mins ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent review looked at 26 studies that examined mental state after smoking cessation.  The review found LESS depression among people who quit, not more.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3923980/

Anything is possible, but based on this, it would be best to look elsewhere for the cause(s) of your complaint.

Also remember that depression is a very treatable disorder, and the treatments are pretty safe.  You wouldn't take a depression-treating pill if it had a 50% chance of killing you, so it would be even more unwise to start using tobacco in the mistaken idea that it could help your mood (it has a 50% chance of killing you).

Also note: schizophrenics are the ones who self-treat with nicotine, not depressives.

Comment: I finally quitted smoking and can confirm that is right. This is all minor mental conditions.